# unique pointer class member

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers

I'm learning about constructors, destructors and memory in a C++ class now. I would like a vector inside a class. I keep getting an error when writing "return magnitudes->at(dimension); " Is there something wrong with this code?

Edit:
sorry, the error was "applying -> to unique pointer instead of raw pointer", this is from Clion, maybe the IDE is wrong?

Other than the error, I'm mainly wrapping it in a smart pointer so there's no memory leak, or is that not possible anyway? Will the destructor always be called (sorry still learning about destructors).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "EuclideanVector.h"
#include "../catch.hpp"
#include <memory>

namespace evec{

    class EuclideanVector{
    public:
        //constructors
        EuclideanVector(): EuclideanVector(1){};
        EuclideanVector(unsigned int size): magnitudes(std::make_unique(new std::vector<double>(size,0.0))){}

        double get(int dimension){
            return magnitudes->at(dimension);
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<std::vector<double>> magnitudes;

    };
}
```

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the exact problem please.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to use `unique_ptr` here. `std::vector` itself is usually very small (probably 12 or so bytes) and stores its contents in the heap.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to **learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: magnitudes(std::make_unique<std::vector<double>>(size,0.0))) would suffice.

Comment: Just use a `std::vector` as a member – no pointers – and it will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here

```
EuclideanVector(unsigned int size): magnitudes(std::make_unique(new std::vector<double>(size,0.0))){}
```

Change this line to

```
EuclideanVector(unsigned int size): magnitudes(std::make_unique<std::vector<double>>(size,0.0)){}
```

Because [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is a template, there is no need to use `new`.